# Get file name of file being uploaded and write it into a text field

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a form with two input fields, one `type=file` and other `type=text`.

I would like to:

1. select a file with `type=file` field to be uploaded using php
2. grab the **file name** of the file being uploaded
3. insert the `upload dir/file_name` into the `type=text` field

The file gets uploaded fine. The problem is i get the `file name` wrong, depends on the browser i'm using.

- **Firefox** works fine and i get: `somepath/file_name.ext`
- **IE(10)** gets me full local file path: `somepath/C:\Users\User\Desktop\file_name.ext`
- **Chrome** gets all cute and returns: `somepath/C:\fakepath\file_name.ext`

How do i solve this? I need **only** the `file_name.ext`, like Firefox does it. Needless to say i need the file name detected and appropriate text field changed as the file is selected and before the form is submitted.

The HTML part:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
  <input name="data_up" id="data_up" type="file" /><br>
  <input name="data" id="data" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo $_POST['data']; } ?>" />
  <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The PHP part (simplified, needs security added):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if ($_FILES["data_up"]["error"] == 0) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["data_up"]["tmp_name"], "somepath/".$_FILES["data_up"]["name"]);
  }
}
```

The JS part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('#data_up').change(function () {
    var fileName = $(this).val();
    $('#data').val('somepath/'+fileName);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

just extract the last string before the last slash .. in your case v is what is returned and x is what you want

```
var v = 'some\\thing\\text.txt';
var x ='';
for(i=v.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  if(v[i]!='/' && v[i]!='\\')
    x = v[i]+x;
  else 
    break;
console.log(x);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/4GMnX/)**

solution 2 :

```
var v = 'some/thing/text.txt';
var y = v.split(/[\\\/]/);
var x = y[y.length-1];
console.log(x);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/3XHrf/)**

Solution 3:

```
var v = 'vava\\text.txt';
console.log(v.replace(/.*[\\\/]/g,''));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/FcNLp/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

The method you are looking for is `basename()`.

So your code will look like:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["data_up"]["tmp_name"], "somepath/".basename($_FILES["data_up"]["name"]));
```

An example in the PHP docs can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Answer (score 0):

"$_FILES["data_up"]["name"]" always gives file name only.

First Debug the code once Just try to print the File data like `print_r ($_FILES['data_up']);` you will understand what you need?